# MVC: Best way to build a View with a list of Models (C# Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi!

I am new to MVC and I don´t know if I am doing it right the way I try to do it, so I need your help.

Think about a trivial form with a listview on it (Just for example). Lets say the listview can hold multible student objects. This student objects consists just of a Name and a Id Number (As I mentioned very simple).

```cs
class student : IModel {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string IDNumber { get; set; }
}

interface IModel {
  string Name { get; set; }
  string IDNumber { get; set; }
}
```

When I use something like this as my model and I want to have a View as  described above is it a good idea to encapsulate my "model" in some kind of a meta model?

Something like:

```cs
//in this example the IModel definition is not part of the student class
class studentModel : IModel {
    List<student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I hope you know what I am trying to explain.

I have to build a container for my model to be able to bind it to the View (So it is just one Model per View).

But if I do it like that my Student object is not part of IModel rather the studentModel is (e.g. to add Observer functionality). But if this is OK how should I access my student object in the View. Sure I can just access the component but is this a good approach? Is it better to build something like a model in a model?

I am a little bit confused as long as there is one student object in one view everything is ok but otherwise my brain is missing some information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't create an interface (`IModel`), but rather a `Student` class only. An interface makes sense (generally speaking) when you want to establish a "contract" of some common behavior, that multiple implementers of that interface should use.

In the view side, the model that the view should accept would be something like `List<Student>` (note the capital S) and that's it.

As a side note, a good example of when you would want an interface is when there's some common characteristic (property) or funcionality (method) that you want to enforce. Let's say your system had not just students, but also professors and administrative staff. You could create an `IPerson` interface with just an `Id` as an enforced common property, then you would have classes `Student`, `Professor`, `Staff` that all implement `IPerson` and then all of them would be enforced, by the language, to have an `Id` property. And in that case you could even build a list view for example of people that its model is `List<IPerson>` (but then of course you'd have to do casting to access every property that's not `Id`...).

Comment: Yes that is exaclty what I mean (sorry it was late yesterday). Sorry for the bad example. I totaly aggree with your usecase of Interfaces and I intend to use it like this.
And you also answered my question to use a List of Models in a View and not add some extra behaviour to the model to Transport to the View.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, but if all you want to access in your view is a `List<Foo>`, there's nothing wrong with making that the model type. You don't need to enclose it in some other object.

Also (as Ofer has just posted) I'm not sure what purpose `IModel` serves here. Standard practice is to have your viewmodel exist for the sole purpose of containing the data for a given view. An interface would imply you intend to use it for something else.

Edit: If you like this answer accept Ofer's which was posted first and is identical.

Comment: Thank you to for your answer. As you mention I mark Ofer´s but yours is good to.